# display multiple attributes of an object in the html page

Tags: html, django

I have started learning django. I was trying to displaying the query result in a html page using this code:

```
<ul>
   {% for book in booklist %}
     <li>{{ book.bid book.name  }}<li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This gives me an error saying,

> Exception Type:    TemplateSyntaxError
>      Exception Value:   Could not parse the remainder: ' book.name' from 'book.bid book.name'

But when i either remove book.bid or book.name, it works fine. How do i make both the attributes to be shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use two separate tags.

```
{% for book in booklist %}
    <li>{{ book.bid }} {{ book.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: and i get an empty list element at the end after all the data. How do i remove that?

Comment: That's determined by the list you pass to your template. How are you querying books (in your view)?

Comment: result = list(Book.objects.filter(name = search_details['name']))

Comment: I don't think there's any need for `list()`. Try `result = Book.objects.filter(name = search_details[name'])`

Comment: No that doesn't change it

Comment: The template is just the code that i have posted, other that closing and opening tags